# Powerpoint VBA delete empty columns?

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I have several Powerpoint files being generated everymonth, these files have several charts with embedded excel tables behind them, for some month some series(columns) are full of zeros, I would like to find a Powerpoint Macro that goes into each chart looks on the embedded excel and deletes columns that are all zeros.

Now I have the code to do it in excel

```
    Sub DeleteColumns()
Dim LR As Long, LC As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long
LR = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious,SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
LC = 52
   For j = LC To 1 Step -1
     For i = LR To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, j).Value = 0 Then
           Columns(j).Delete
        Exit For
     End If
   Next i
Next j
End Sub
```

And its working, I just dont know how to reference all the charts inside the powerpoint and then target the embedded excel tables behing them.

Many Thanks

Comment: You'll need to use the excel object from powerpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose all the underlying excel chart like so.

I'm not sure of how you are looking to remove the zero columns so suggest you add this in at the spot highlighted below.

```
Sub ChangeChartData()

Dim pptChart As Chart
Dim pptChartData As ChartData
Dim xlWorkbook As Object
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape

 For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.HasChart Then
                Set pptChart = shp.Chart
                Set pptChartData = pptChart.ChartData
                pptChartData.Activate
                Set pptWorkbook = pptChartData.Workbook
                'your delete code here
                pptWorkbook.Close True
            End If
        Next
Next
Set pptWorkbook = Nothing
Set pptChartData = Nothing
 Set pptChart = Nothing

End Sub
```